# BOM - multiple child to one parent relationship

Tags: sql, many-to-many, parent-child, data-modeling, hierarchy

i have the following table structure (dynamic hierarchy structure) for a bill of materials (BOM):

| ID | ParentID | BOMLevel | BOMType | Name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 1 | EndProduct | PName1 |
| 2 | NULL | 1 | EndProduct | PName2 |
| 3 | 1 | 2 | Assemblies | AsseName1 |
| 4 | 1 | 2 | Assemblies | AsseName2 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | Assemblies | AsseName3 |
| 6 | 3 | 3 | SubAssemblies | SubAsseName1 |
| 7 | 4 | 3 | SubAssemblies | SubAsseName2 |
| 8 | 6,7 | 4 | RawMaterial | RawMName1 |
| 9 | 6,7 | 4 | RawMaterial | RawNName1 |

How can i connect one child to many parents?
here e.g. both raw materials are used in both SubAssemblies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some many-to-many relationship between your BOM entities.

That means you need a join table -- also known as a self-to-self bridge table -- to represent them. Let's call it BOM_PARENT. It has a definition like this:

```sql
CREATE TABLE BOM_PARENT (
  ID int NOT NULL,
  ParentID int NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (ID, ParentID),
  UNIQUE KEY (ParentID, ID)
);
```

When a row is *present* in this table, it means a BOM item has a particular parent BOM item. Thus, it's possible for a BOM item to have multiple parents, and for a parent item to have multiple children (careful with that; your BOMs otherwise may become tangled up).

In this case you remove the ParentID from your BOM table.

This query gets you your original data. [Fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.6&fiddle=b0553d4f7c254bbb1a2d10dbe1e361b9).

```sql
SELECT BOM.ID, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(BOM_PARENT.ParentID) Parents,
       BOM.BOMLevel, BOM.BOMType, BOM.Name
  FROM BOM
  LEFT JOIN BOM_PARENT ON BOM.ID = BOM_PARENT.ID
 GROUP BY  BOM.ID, BOM.BOMLevel, BOM.BOMType, BOM.Name
```

Comment: brilliant! Thank you. 
Is the BOM_PARENT kind of a bridge table?

Comment: Maybe it is a stupid question, in practice I would enter data in the BOM table manually (or via excel). Do I have to enter the BOM_PARENT table manually as well? So which ID has which parent?

Comment: Yes, you'll have to fill in both tables. That might be a pain in the axx neck. You might ask another question about how to populate these tables.